# Prompt a message if user click no on XL message "Do you want to save the changes?" on leaving

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a workbook where I want to be sure user is really sure he want to quit without saving changes. Is there a way to prompt a message if user click no on XL message "Do you want to save the changes?" on leaving?

I know there is a BeforeSave event but this one is triggered BEFORE the XL prompt and in my case, I would like AFTER.

Example:

```
- User click the X for leaving the Workbook.
- XL prompt user for saving changes.
- User click NO.
- I would like to prompt again something like "ARE YOU SURE?"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Workbook_Deactivate event fires after the save dialog is dismissed.

You will need to show a modal MsgBox and handle the responce, issue Thisworkbook.Save if required

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then
        res = MsgBox("Save Now?", vbYesNo, "Book Not Saved")
        If res = vbYes Then
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Has the side effect that if more than one book is open, switching between them can fire the meesage too